# Error on linking custom actions to user interface push button control

Tags: wix

I want to trigger some custom action by clicking some button.

I get return value 1 but the custom action did not run.

This is my log:

```
Action start 17:09:39: CA1.

MSI (c) (08:00) [17:09:39:220]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Users\ARKADY~1\AppData\Local\Temp\MSI87D6.tmp, Entrypoint: CustomAction1

MSI (c) (08:EC) [17:09:39:222]: Cloaking enabled.

MSI (c) (08:EC) [17:09:39:223]: Attempting to enable all disabled privileges before calling Install on Server

MSI (c) (08:EC) [17:09:39:224]: Connected to service for CA interface.
Action ended 17:09:39: CA1. Return value 1.
```

My custom action is:

```
    [CustomAction]
    public static ActionResult CustomAction1(Session session)
    {
        session.Log("Begin CustomAction1");

        return ActionResult.Success;
    }
```

As you can see no "Begin CustomAction1" entry in the logs.

My custom action Config:

```
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

From wix code declaring CA:

```
<Binary Id="CA"  SourceFile="$(var.CustomAction1.TargetDir)$(var.CustomAction1.TargetName).CA.dll" />
<CustomAction Id="CA1" BinaryKey="CA" DllEntry="CustomAction1" Execute="immediate" Return="check"/>
```

UI binding:

```
    <Control Id="ManualUpdateButton" Type="PushButton" X="14" Y="188" Width="95" Height="17" Text="Manual Update">
      <Publish Event="DoAction" Value="CA1" Order="1">1</Publish>
    </Control>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The custom action is running, it's just not logging anything. That's a limitation in MSI -- you can't write to the log from a custom action invoked by `DoAction` in the UI.

Comment: I guess manually writing a string array to a file it is then!